# Extract x,y component of two time series from a plot?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I am currently having issues to extract information from two time series sequences. I have plotted the sequences `t1,t2` using matplotlib. I am interested to extract the `x,y` components of the diagonal which has the maximum similarity to start with .

I am working creating a function `Similarity` that , takes in two sequences and outputs a similarity score between them

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
Similarity_score =Similarity(t1,t2) 
plt.imshow(Similarity_score)
```

The area colored blue is where the most the time series are most sychronized. Is there a way to do it in python or if there package to do so . Image attached below . [image: plot of time series1 and series2]

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? It's hard to help without context.

Comment: Added , how i approached it

Comment: Without example time series and the Similarity function it becomes very difficult to replicate the problem

Comment: I have removed the `PIL` tag as it seems unrelated to anything in your question.

Comment: I tried with  `Dynamic Time Wrapping `

Comment: As I understood the pixel that indicates the most similarity, has the coldest color in the image, is that correct? so the task is to find that pixel?

Comment: Hi yes, it is ideally like that. I guess getting a pixel value would also , return the corresponding , `x,y` co-ordinates and thus one can get we can get the time component of `t1` and `t2` . so basically `x_comp = t1` and ỳ_comp =t2`

Comment: as you mentioned, if I user the color code as a threshold, i can probably find the associated indices ? Perhaps just to extract the area where it is dark blue. Is it possible to do so ?